# Possible to use wide-character members in Python extension objects?

Tags: python, c, unicode, python-extensions

It's simple to create a member for an object in a Python C extension with a base type of `char *`, using the `T_STRING` define in the `PyMemberDef` declaration.

Why does there not seem to be an equivalent for `wchar_t *`? And if there actually is one, what is it?

e.g.

`struct object` contains `char *text`

`PyMemberDef` array has `{"text", T_STRING, offsetof(struct object, text), READONLY, "This is a normal character string."}`

versus something like

`struct object` contains `wchar_t *wtext`

`PyMemberDef` array has `{"wtext", T_WSTRING, offsetof(struct object, wtext), READONLY, "This is a wide character string"}`

I understand that something like `PyUnicode_AsString()` and its related methods can be used to encode the data in UTF-8, store it in a basic char string, and decode later, but doing it that way would require wrapping the generic `getattr` and `setattr` methods/functions with ones that account for the encoded text, and it's not very useful when you want character arrays of fixed element size within a struct and don't want the effective number of characters that can be stored in it to vary.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but: depending on how Python is compiled, Py_UNICODE might be wchar_t. Python can either use 2 bytes per unicode character (i.e. wchar), or 4. So C code needs to use the PyUnicode_* functions to handle unicode strings without assuming what format they're stored in.

Comment: @Thomas: `wchar_t` is either two or four bytes, depending on platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `wchar_t` directly is not portable. Instead, Python defines the [`Py_UNICODE` type](http://docs.python.org/c-api/unicode.html#Py_UNICODE) as the storage unit for a Unicode character.

Depending on the platform, `Py_UNICODE` may be defined as `wchar_t` if available, or an unsigned short/integer/long, the width of which will vary depending on how Python is configured (UCS2 vs UCS4) and the architecture and C compiler used.   You can find the relevant definitions in [`unicodeobject.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5395f96588d4/Include/unicodeobject.h#l94).

For your use case, your object can have an attribute that is a Unicode string, using `T_OBJECT`:

```
static struct PyMemberDef attr_members[] = {
  { "wtext", T_OBJECT, offsetof(PyAttrObject, wtext), READONLY, "wide string"}
  ...
```

You can perform type checking in the object's initializer:

```
...
if (!PyUnicode_CheckExact(arg)) {
    PyErr_Format(PyExc_ValueError, "arg must be a unicode string");
    return NULL;
}
Py_INCREF(arg);
self->wtext = arg;
...
```

If you ever need to iterate over the low-level characters in the Unicode string, there is a macro which returns a `Py_UNICODE *`:

```
int i = 0;
Py_ssize_t size = PyUnicode_GetSize(self->wtext);
Py_UNICODE *chars = PyUnicode_AS_UNICODE(self->wtext);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // use chars[i]
    ...
```

Comment: I see. If I'm not mistaken, though, the Python reference seems to recommend the use of `T_OBJECT_EX` over `T_OBJECT` due to how certain cases are handled.

Comment: Yep, you could use `T_OBJECT_EX` instead. For a `READONLY` attribute (which cannot be deleted) a `T_OBJECT` should also work fine. Choice also depends on whether you want a `NULL` value for `self->wtext` to raise an error or just return `None`, which really depends on the behavior you want your object to exhibit.